# C++ structure/array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, structure

I have a C++ array or structure initialization issue that I have not been able to resolve.

I have a 4-level nested structure. Each level is actually the same 48 bytes wrapped in the structure next level up. The issue is when the structure is initialized and declared as a scalar value, it is correctly initialized with the provided values. However, when it is declared as a single element array, all 48 bytes become zeros, as shown below. Unfortunately the structures are too complicated to be pasted here.

If I define 4 simple structures, one containing another, with the innermost one containing the same 12 unsigned integers, then it is initialized correctly, even if it is declared in an array.

Has anyone experienced similar issues? What am I missing? What compiler flags, options, etc could lead to such a problem? Appreciate any comments and help.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bls12_381/fq.hpp"

static constexpr embedded_pairing::bls12_381::Fq scalar = {
        {{{.std_words = {0x1c7238e5, 0xcf1c38e3, 0x786f0c70, 0x1616ec6e, 0x3a6691ae, 0x21537e29, 
                         0x4d9e82ef, 0xa628f1cb, 0x2e5a7ddf, 0xa68a205b, 0x47085aba, 0xcd91de45}}}}
};

static constexpr embedded_pairing::bls12_381::Fq array[1] = {
        {{{{.std_words = {0x1c7238e5, 0xcf1c38e3, 0x786f0c70, 0x1616ec6e, 0x3a6691ae, 0x21537e29, 
                          0x4d9e82ef, 0xa628f1cb, 0x2e5a7ddf, 0xa68a205b, 0x47085aba, 0xcd91de45}}}}}
};

void print_struct(const char *title, const uint8_t *cbuf, int len)
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("[%s] %d\n", title, len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i % 30 == 0 && i != 0)
            printf("\n");
        else if ((i % 10 == 0 || i % 20 == 0) && i != 0)
            printf("  ");
        printf("%02X ", cbuf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void run_tests() 
{
    print_struct("scalar", (const uint8_t *) &scalar, sizeof(scalar));
    print_struct("array", (const uint8_t *) &array[0], sizeof(array[0]));
}
```

```
[scalar] 48
E5 38 72 1C E3 38 1C CF 70 0C   6F 78 6E EC 16 16 AE 91 66 3A   29 7E 53 21 EF 82 9E 4D CB F1
28 A6 DF 7D 5A 2E 5B 20 8A A6   BA 5A 08 47 45 DE 91 CD

[array] 48
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I've just narrowed down the example.
The following is a complete and standalone example. I also forgot to mention that the initialization on Linux using g++ 9.3.0, -std=c++17, gets the expected results of all FF's. However, on an embedded device, the inherited structure gets all 0's.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Data {
    uint32_t words;
};

struct Overlay {
    Data val;
};

struct Inherit : Data {
};

static Overlay overlay[1] = {
        {{.words = 0xffffffff}}
};

static Inherit inherit[1] = {
        {{.words = 0xffffffff}}
};

void print_struct(const char *title, const uint8_t *cbuf, int len)
{
    printf("[%s] %d\n", title, len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%02X ", cbuf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() 
{
    print_struct("overlay", (const uint8_t *) &overlay[0], sizeof(overlay[0]));   // FF FF FF FF
    print_struct("inherit", (const uint8_t *) &inherit[0], sizeof(inherit[0]));   // 00 00 00 00  <-- incorrect?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first you assign `array[1]`... and try to print `array[0]`... is this ok for you ?

Comment: is it possible to share with us your `embedded_pairing::bls12_381::Fq` type ?

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: I could not reproduce, using a dummied up `Fq` structure of various depths. Which compiler/version are you using? What compiler options? And case we get that [mre], which would be code in the question that we can copy-and-paste to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @tony_merguez the array is initialized to have one element to exhibit the problem. Therefore, I used array[0] to print the single element.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).